# The parent grey div hides the bottom part of the lime box

Tags: html, css, position

The parent grey div **hides the bottom part of the lime box**.

- Can I keep the bottom part of the lime box visible?
- What is the right way of using **overflow: hidden;** here?

It is also important to save 100% width of the parent grey box.

[Example 1 - Zoom in issue](http://jsfiddle.net/DbJSf/1/)

[Example 2 - Zoom out issue](http://jsfiddle.net/3GQkq/)

**How can we make the grey line 100% width (for both zoom in and out) ?**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<style>
/* Start BG RECT */
.bg-rect {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 50px;
    left:0; right:0;    /* Required to be 100% 100% */
    min-width: 980px;   /* max for iPad */  
    height: 263px;
}

#bg-rect-important {
    overflow: hidden;   /* Disable right bg breaking by words on the right! */
    /* overflow hidden: disallows child be taller then parent?! */
    background-color: #656565;
}

/* Start BASE RECT */
.base-rect {
    position: relative; /* margin: auto works only with position: relative  */ 
    margin: 0 auto;     /* Centralize! */
/*!SPACE>*/top:32px; width:940px;
    /*left: -300px; /* unfortunately scroll doen't work */
}

#base-rect-lime {
    background-color: #3F3;
    height:249px;
}

    /* Start LIME RECT : left, right */
    #left-text {
        position:absolute;
        left:-200px; 
        width:200px; height:218px;
    }
    #right-text {
        position:absolute;
        right:-200px;
        width:200px; height:218px;
    }
    /* End LIME RECT : left, right */

/* End BASE RECT */
/* End BG RECT */
</style>

</head>

<body>

<div class="bg-rect" id="bg-rect-important">
    <div class="base-rect" id="base-rect-lime">
        <div id="left-text"></div>       
        <div id="right-text"></div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question? If you want the bottom part of the lime box visible, there is no correct way to use `overflow: hidden`

Comment: Perhaps you meant something like this - http://jsfiddle.net/TYcz7/

Comment: Lime box is taller. It's bottom part should be also visible from the bottom (lower than the bottom edge of the grey rectangle).

Comment: I mean the lime box child should be over the parent div.
But parent div cuts out a part of the child.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is what you want:

```
#bg-rect-important {
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background-color: #656565;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/h2E7v/

Comment: I tried it once. Does is really work?
I have changed the id to yours, but there is no result...

Comment: Your question was / remains unclear. Try adding `width:100%` to your element

Comment: Can you please show your result?.. it might be correct, but may be I reproduce it in the wrong way.  Lime box should be visible outside of the grey rectangle (child should be over the parent).  Thanks!

Comment: see this - http://jsfiddle.net/h2E7v/1/

The element that your absolutely positioned element is in must be position relative, with the desired width. This is hard to reproduce in a fiddle without wrapping it.

Comment: Yes! I can specify my question! Here http://jsfiddle.net/DbJSf/
it's outside - this is ok, but when you zoom there is no 100% of the grey box on the right side :) The problem is overflow option.

Comment: Zoom won't change how anything looks or relates to eachother. It just makes it bigger.

Comment: One more specification! "Ears" will not allow the grey box to be 100% wide. Here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/DbJSf/1/
The left and right boxes are also the reason.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3GQkq/

You need to explain this better, like with a drawing of what you want.

Comment: Please zoom out. You'll see that my example has (zoom in issue), but your has the same zoom out issue. Thanks for help! I can't cope with it... I try to be comprehensive. That was my question. I tried different ways to resolve it, but I see that it required very deep html, css knowledge.

Comment: Anyway, I think you have helped me a lot.
Know I now how to write mote distinct new question.
That you for the answer. Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0):

We think,

```
#bg-rect-important {
background-color: #656565;
}
```

will make your the bottom part of the lime box visible

It also save 100% width of the parent grey box

Hope this help you.

Comment: Please try max zoom on the screen; then scroll to the top right angle; the grey box is not 100% width.

It's 100% width without zooming.